# MATLAB - array of objects is empty after exiting function

Tags: matlab, oop

```
classdef ObjData < matlab.mixin.Copyable
  properties
    id;
  end

  methods

    function obj = ObjData(path)           
        [~,name] = fileparts(path);
        obj.id = name;
    end
  end
end

classdef StudyData
  properties
    objs = []
  end

  methods
    function obj = StudyData()
        obj.itarate_study_folder();
    end   
  end

  methods (Access = private)     
    function obj = itarate_study_folder(obj)
        flist = findfiles('*.obj',obj.path);
        if isempty((flist)) == 0
            for k=1:length(flist)
                 if ~isempty(obj.objs)
                    obj.objs(end+1) = ObjData(flist{k});
                 else
                    obj.objs = ObjData(flist{k});
                 end
            end
        end
    end
  end
end
```

In this code I try to populate the `StudyData.objs` array with elements of type `ObjData`.

I try to to so in `StudyData.itarate_study_folder()` function.

The issue is that as long a I'm in the scope of `itarate_study_folder()`, the array looks ok, but when exiting this function, the array is empty again.

I also tried to pre-allocate the array before entering `itarate_study_folder()` with empty objects, but it didn't help.

Could you help me figuring out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You define the function as

```
function obj = itarate_study_folder(obj)
```

So when you call the function, you need to collect the output argument:

```
obj = obj.itarate_study_folder();
```

In MATLAB, all arguments are passed by value by default. `obj.itarate_study_folder()` is the same as `itarate_study_folder(obj)`, the object is passed by value, not by reference. This means that the function has a copy of that object.

---

If you want the syntax

```
obj.itarate_study_folder();
```

to modify the object, then the object has to be a handle. To make it so, convert your class into a handle class by inheriting from `handle`:

```
classdef StudyData < handle
```

For handle classes, the function should not return the object:

```
function itarate_study_folder(obj)
```

However, handle classes should only be used for classes that manage some resource, like a graphical display or a file. Such objects can in general not be copied, as multiple copies would free the resource multiple times.

For objects that only store data, use a non-handle class. Your `ObjData` class, by inheriting from `matlab.mixin.Copyable`, is a handle class. It doesn’t seem to manage storage, so it would be better if this were a plain class.

Note that MATLAB uses lazy copying, which is a different approach to efficiency than passing data by reference. Don’t use handle classes if you think using them will speed up code by avoiding copies, it won’t.